# SUMIFS with and + or criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, sumifs, array-formulas

I would like to sum all values in C where column A is in {"A", "B"} *and* column B is in {"W", "X"} -- this is the orange records. It is the "overlap" of the two conditions. The answer should be 8. I thought the `SUM(SUMIFS(` approach would work, but it does not.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work but one of the arrays must be horizontal and the other vertical:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,{"A","B"},B:B,{"W";"X"}))
```

The `,` makes it horizontal and the `;` vertical.  The limit is two arrays a third can not be added.

[image]

---

To add more than two one must switch to something else.

One can use SUMPRODUCT, with ISNUMBER(MATCH()) for each Criteria:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A9,{"A","B"},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:B9,{"W","X"},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1:C9,{"D","E"},0)),D1:D9)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - is there a way to "trick" it to add a third? Say in another column? In other words, if you want to extend this to 5+ columns of criteria, is it possible? Feels like this is just "filtering" the table.

Comment: no as stated above `SUM(SUMIFS())` can only use two arrays.  You will need to change to `SUMPRODUCT()` to allow for multiple, but that has draw backs as it is an array type formula.

Comment: See edit @JasonAizkalns for a method that works for more than two.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=sum(sumifs(c1:c9, a1:a9, {"A","B"}, b1:b9, transpose({"W","X"})))
```